# Find number of occurences of event per day - SQL

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm trying to set up some monitoring in my SQL database.

```
select
        gn.Goal_Name_
        ,gn.EventTimestamp as   Timestamp
        --,Max(EventTimestamp) as   Timestamp
        from(
            select CASE when substr(GoalName,1,3)='MSD' then 'MSD' when substr(GoalName,1,5)='https' then 'https' else goalname END as Goal_Name_ 
                    
                    ,EventTimestamp
                from    CG.Goal as goal
        )gn
        group by 1,2
```

Produces a table with a structure like:

| Goal_Name_ | Timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| MSD | 05.03.2021 11:05:20.162 |
| Logout | 18.01.2022 20:07:29.799 |
| Login | 23.01.2022 09:12:16.597 |
| etc | etc |

The problem i'm having is finding a way to count each distinct Goal Name for each day. Find the daily occurence really.

Comment: You should include sample data which matches the query.

Comment: edited the question to make it more clear that the query produces the following table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. The only thing missing is converting your timestamp to date and count the number of rows.

```sql
select
     gn.Goal_Name_
     ,CAST(gn.EventTimestamp AS DATE FORMAT 'YYYY/MM/DD') as eventDay
     ,Count(*) as   GoalsCount
     from(
          select CASE when substr(GoalName,1,3)='MSD' then 'MSD' when 
          substr(GoalName,1,5)='https' then 'https' else goalname END as Goal_Name_ 
          ,EventTimestamp
          from CG.Goal as goal
     )gn
group by 1,2
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for! Thank you so much :D Hope your year is blessed